# How to Resize UserControl & its inner controls on window resize in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, window-resize

I am new to WPF programming. I have a UserControl which is Content of DocumentPanel in Ribbon Window. *Problem is when i Resize the window it Clip the Control and their is not scroll bar*. What to do to resolve this problem?
**The Controls inside UserControl must resize along with the Window**. Any idea?

Here is my Markup:

```
<UserControl xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"  x:Class="XproWPF.UserControls.usContactForm"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="1024" MinHeight="600" MinWidth="1024">

        <Grid x:Name="grdContactMain" ShowGridLines="False">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"></Setter>
                </Style>

            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <GroupBox Header="Internet " HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid  ShowGridLines="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
                        <RowDefinition  />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!--<Button Content="Email1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" Click="Button_Click"/>-->
                        <Button Name="BtnEmail"  Content="Email" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100">

                        </Button>
                        <Button Click="btnEmailExpand_Click" Name="btnEmailExpand" Content=" + " HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Button.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu x:Name="emailContextMenu" />
                            </Button.ContextMenu>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" MinWidth="445">
                        <TextBox Name="txtEmail1"  MinWidth="445" Text="Email" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <TextBox Name="txtEmail2" MinWidth="445" Text="Email2" Visibility="Collapsed"  Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <TextBox Name="txtEmail3"  MinWidth="445" Text="Email3" Visibility="Collapsed"   Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="Display as"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <Label Content="Web Page Address" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                    <Label Content="IM Address" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>

            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="Phone Numbers " HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid  ShowGridLines="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                        <!--<RowDefinition  />-->

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Name="BtnContactBusiness" Content="Business" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" Click="BtnContactBusiness_Click"/>
                        <Button Name="BtnContactBusinessExpand" Content=" + " Click="BtnBusinessExpand_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Button.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu x:Name="businessContextMenu" />
                            </Button.ContextMenu>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="busniess text"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
                        <Button Content=" + "  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="Home text" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>


                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Fax" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
                        <Button Content=" + "  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Mobile" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
                        <Button Content=" + "  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>

            <GroupBox Header="Addresses"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3" >
                <Grid  ShowGridLines="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="35*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />


                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="34*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="33*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="33*" />

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Name="BtnContactAddressHome" Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" Click="BtnContactAddressHome_Click"/>
                        <Button Content=" + " Click="BtnHomeExpand_Click" Name="BtnHomeExpand" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Button.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu x:Name="homeContextMenu" />
                            </Button.ContextMenu>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Work" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
                        <Button Content=" + "  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Mailing" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
                        <Button Content=" + "  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Image Grid.Column="2"  Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="/XtremeProcurementWPF;component/Images/description_img.png" />

                </Grid>

            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="Social Media" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid  ShowGridLines="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--<RowDefinition Height="20*" />-->
                        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"   Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Website" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" />
                        <Button Content=" + "  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="website text" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>


                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"   Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Facebook" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
                        <Button Content=" + "  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="facebook text" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>


                    <StackPanel  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"    Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Linkedin" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
                        <Button Content=" + "  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="linked text" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                    <StackPanel  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"     Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Twitter" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
                        <Button Content=" + "  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="Twitter text" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>


                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>

            <Image Grid.Column="1"   Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="/XproWPF;component/Images/business-card2.jpg"/>
            <GroupBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" >
                <Grid  ShowGridLines="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />

                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
                        <RowDefinition  />
                        <!--<RowDefinition Height="16*" />-->
                        <!--<RowDefinition Height="16*" />-->

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Name="BtnContactFullname" Content="Full Name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="BtnContactFullname_Click"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit IsTextEditable="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <Label Content="Gender" Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="/XproWPF;component/Images/description_img.png" />
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>



        </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the UserControl you have included. I think it is probably the way that the parent is presenting it. Have you tried adding a ScrollViewer to the parent and adding your control to the ScrollViewer?

Comment: In addition you may need to set the MinWidth property on some of your controls Grid ColumnDefinitions to stop them disappearing.

Comment: no i have tried to applying to the ribbon window but the controls size exapands dont know why? Can we apply it to documentpanel or is their any other way to do the same..! so that it will resize on mobile device too..?